# How do I keep playing random songs?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

Say I have a list of songs. I essentially want my app to pick a random song from the list, play it, and when thats complete, pick another random song, play that and so on and on forever.

This is what I'm currently trying:

I make a delegate of AVAudioPlayer. I use the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying function to keep track of when a song is complete. When this function is called, I would ideally pick a new song to play. However, the problem with this is that AVAudioPlayer cannot be assigned a new song.

I also tried looking into AVQueuePlayer, which can be assigned a new song, however, it doesn't have an audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying function.

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Why don't you create a new `AVAudioPlayer` ?

Comment: You can track your variable content be changing as the "audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying" event runs replay the same variable with a new audio.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr What do you mean create a new player?

Comment: @eliasRuizHz Sorry, I'm not really sure what you mean. How can I change use new audio with the same variable?

Comment: @Riei If you cannot change the song of your current `AVAudioPlayer` after playback ended, just discard it and create a new one with the new song you want to play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**a. You can prepare your playlist this way:**

```
var Player1 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1", ofType: "mp3")!), error: nil)

var sound1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1", ofType: "mp3")!)
var sound2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("2", ofType: "mp3")!)
var sound3 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("3", ofType: "mp3")!)
var sound4 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("4", ofType: "mp3")!)

Player1.prepareToPlay()
Player1.play()
```

**a. And when your event "audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying" is triggered:**

```
Player1 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound2, error: nil)
Player1.prepareToPlay()
Player1.play()
```

**b. Or you can prepare the tracks before making the change:**

```
var sound2 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("2", ofType: "mp3")!), error: nil).prepareToPlay()
```

**b. And when your event "audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying" is triggered:**

```
Player1 = sound2
Player1.play()
```